# How do I stop my C drive appearing also as D on Windows 10 file explorer?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, drive-letter

Am running Windows 10 Pro v1803. At some point a mysterious clone of my C drive showed up as D. This is an SSD. The drive letter doesn't appear in DISKPART. Nor does it show in Disk management console. I run as a regular user, and if I switch to another account on the machine, it doesn't appear. I have tried to remove the registry key for delegated folders, but that doesn't work. I have also tried the various options here: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/107032-remove-drive-letter-windows-10-a.html

[image: My drives as shown in Explorer]

[image: D does appears in Disk Manager]

Comment: Hmm what happens if you plug in an USB or something like that and assign the D letter to that (it should be free according to Disk Management) and then refresh the My PC view?

Comment: In Disk Management, right click C: and choose Change Drive Letters... in the box that opens do you see D: listed as an assigned drive letter?

Comment: In regedit check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices` Is D: there?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk. Nope, no D in there.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator No D in the drive letters.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting delegated folders is done under two keys, although I don't think
that this is your problem:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders
```

You could also start a Command Prompt (cmd) and enter the command :

```
subst D: /d
```

If successful, the virtual drive should disappear immediately.
No need to restart Windows or anything.

Comment: I had tried both of those with no luck. The subst command doesn't recognize the D drive as being legit.

Comment: Has this happened very recently?

Comment: Last few weeks.

Comment: If you still have a system restore point from a time that it worked, you may rollback to it. I would hate to advise you to do an [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) because of such a problem - I would rather counsel ignoring this phantom.